# Spark SQl - Using a variable in a string and use the string to compare with column value

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I want to use a variable inside a string in Spark SQL and I will use this string to compare with a column value. How can I achieve this ?

e.g.

spark.conf.set("var.env", 'dev')

%sql

-- This works fine

select * from application_tbl where environment = '${var.name}'

-- This does not work

select * from application_tbl where proj_environmnet = 'project' + ${var.name} + 'some-string'